# Display list in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, list, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm using Android Studio to make my Android app.

I have this code which outputs to console all the apps installed on my Android phone.

How can I change this so that it outputs the list to a RecyclerView on my Android app instead of outputting it to console?

```
package com.example.launcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class AppInfo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_info);

    }

    class PInfo {
        private String appname = "";
        private String pname = "";
        private String versionName = "";
        private int versionCode = 0;
        private Drawable icon;
        private void prettyPrint() {
           System.out.println(appname + "t" + pname + "t" + versionName + "t" + versionCode + "t");
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
        }
        return apps;
    }

    private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
        ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue ;
            }
            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[According to the Android Developer Training](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html):

1. You need to add an RecyclerView to your activity's / fragment's
   layout
2. Create a custom Adapter that you can pass to the RecyclerView
3. Create a layout that your Adapter can use to render a single item

Activity / Fragment:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new PInfoAdapter(apps);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Adapter:

```
public class PInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PInfoAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private PInfo[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public PInfoAdapter(PInfo[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public PInfoAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                               .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ...
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position].getAppName());

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Please take a look at the link above and let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Ok so i've had a look at your code and the link but i'm faced with a ton of errors. Here are 3 screenshots http://imgur.com/a/hsd6G The first screenshot is from my AppInfo class. All the errors are "Cannot resolve symbol 'mRecyclerView ' " and so on.  The second and third screenshot are from my PInfoAdapter class. The rest of the errors in this class are "cannot resolve symbol......" And in my xml file I have the Recyclerview code that is in the example on the link

Comment: Puh.. you should follow the android training along to get an basic idea of an android app's structure. I delivered you some snippets to simplify your edits but I didn't deliver you EVERYTHING. First I updated some spots where i forgot to adjust the adapter's name. You need to create member variables for all variables beginning with an m. That should resolve some issus. Then you need to create the needed layouts and assign the ids. Then you need to add getter and setter to your class PInfo. I hope you can fix some mistakes, but I can't explain every bit. For further issues ask specifically.